# Connection of Web Interface with Tensorflow

Tags: python, web, tensorflow

I am currently working on a project where I get input data in a Web Interface and send it to a python script for processing.

The python script opens a session, restores the desired TF model and process the data.

This way, I have to restore the model every time the user sends new data. To restore the model takes though 1:40 min , which is a problem for me.

The solution I came up is to use two python script, one that creates a session and set it as default, then loads the model in that session and another script that gets the default session and default graph and processes the data. That way the model will be loaded it once and I will be able to use it for all user requests. The code looks smth like below..

```
Script 1 - loads the graph:
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    sess = tf.Session()
   with sess.as_default():
       #Load the graph
       #sess.close This is I leave in comments, to keep the session open 

Script 2 - process data:
with tf.get_default_graph():
     with tf.get_default_session() as sess:
     #process data
```

This solution did not work, The information for the loaded model is lost. Is like having a for inside another for and then split it, normal that it does not work!

Can you suggest me another way to keep this model loaded always, so as I can avoid this delay every time a user wants to process smth new?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you importing anything from script 1 to script 2?

Comment: Are you re-running for each for user request? You need to keep your process live, TensorFlow Serving implements something like this

Comment: Thanks for telling me about Tensorflow Serving, from what I read this is what I need. Do not know, how I did not come up with it till now. Thank you! :)